# list of occurences of references

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, indexing

I need a list like the `list of figures` for `\ref` entries in the text to instances of a custom `Theorem` environment. Here's a MWE with a handbuilt example. The solution should add features to this code I built using the answer to [write contents of an environment to document and toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60738/write-contents-of-an-environment-to-document-and-toc).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\gref}[1]{%
   [Goal~\ref{goal:#1}]
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@goal[1]{%
\addpenalty{\@highpenalty}%
\vskip \z@ \@plus \p@ 
\begingroup
\parindent\z@
\rightskip\@pnumwidth
\parfillskip-\@pnumwidth 
\leavevmode #1\nobreak\hfil\nobreak\null\par 
\penalty\@highpenalty
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\egregaddtocontents}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\l@goal{#1}}}

% arrange goal numbering by chapter
\newtheorem{Goal}{Goal}[chapter]

\NewEnviron{goal}[1]{%
\begin{Goal}
\label{goal:#1}
%{\em label:} #1 %comment in/out to restore/suppress printing label
\normalfont{}\noindent
\BODY
\egregaddtocontents{\BODY}
}
[\end{Goal}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{First}

\begin{goal}{firstfirst}
learn more \LaTeX
\end{goal}

\begin{goal}{firstsecond}
spend time on content, not \LaTeX
\end{goal}

stuff

\chapter{Second}

\begin{goal}{secondfirst}
have fun in any case
\end{goal}

Chapter contents here, referring to some goals:
\section{whatever}

Reference to a chapter 1 goal: \gref{firstsecond}

Reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst} 

\section{another}

Second reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}

\chapter*{List of Goal References}

Built by hand, should be automated. Format not yet specified.

\begin{itemize}
\item \gref{firstfirst} 
learn more \LaTeX

\item \gref{firstsecond} 
spend time on content, not \LaTeX
\begin{itemize}
\item Section 2.1, page 5 [link to that page]
\end{itemize} 

\item \gref{secondfirst} 
have fun in any case
\begin{itemize}
\item Section 2.1, page 5 [link to that page]
\item Section 2.2, page 5 [link to that page]
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Here's the list from the MWE. The format is `\itemize` but that's just temporary - the solution should allow me to change it easily.

[image: handbuilt list of goals]

Perhaps there's already a package that does the job. If not, perhaps build on top of or cannibalize code that creates the index and the list of figures, since I require features from both.

Comment: Maybe this could be interesting for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49597/10570. I think it is very similar to your problem.

Comment: @Holle That's certainly promising. My application seems to call for a list of lists, with back references. I might be able to use `tocloft` to write that myself and answer my own question - but I hope someone else finds the challenge entrancing before I get around to it.

Comment: @Holle You could have pointed me at this too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32401/footnote-backreference-with-hyperref. Now someone (you or me or someone else) can combine this backreference solution with the list solution ...

Comment: Just use the hyperref-package in the tocloft-example from my first comment. With this package the table entries are hyperlinks back to the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some adjustments to be made. Here's something that should work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[intoc]
\makeindex[name=goals,title=Goal References,columns=1,intoc]

\newcommand{\gref}[1]{%
   [Goal~\ref{goal:#1}]
   \index[goals]{Goal~\getrefnumber{goal:#1}!Section \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@goal[1]{%
  \addpenalty{\@highpenalty}%
  \vskip \z@ \@plus \p@ 
  \begingroup
  \parindent\z@
  \rightskip\@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth 
  \leavevmode #1\nobreak\hfil\nobreak\null\par 
  \penalty\@highpenalty
  \endgroup}

\newcommand{\egregaddtocontents}[1]{%   
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\l@goal{#1}}}

% arrange goal numbering by chapter
\newtheorem{Goal}{Goal}[chapter]

% define a shorthand to be able to get at \BODY with \expandafter    
\newcommand\indexgoal[1]{\goalindex[goals]{Goal~\theGoal!#1}}
% save a copy of \index
\let\goalindex\index
\NewEnviron{goal}[1]{%
\begin{Goal}
   \label{goal:#1}%
   % here we neutralize \index so that it won't do damages
   \begingroup\renewcommand\index[2][]{}%
   % but the main command uses \goalindex, so it's safe
   \expandafter\indexgoal\expandafter{\BODY}%
   \egregaddtocontents{\BODY}
   \endgroup
   %{\em label:} #1 %comment in/out to restore/suppress printing label
   \normalfont{}\noindent
   \BODY
}
[\end{Goal}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{First}

\tracingmacros=1

\begin{goal}{firstfirst} 
learn more \LaTeX
\end{goal}

\tracingmacros=0

\begin{goal}{firstsecond}
spend time on content, not \LaTeX
\end{goal}

stuff\index{stuff}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{goal}{secondfirst}
have fun in any case\index{fun}
\end{goal}

Chapter contents here, referring to some goals:
\section{whatever}

Reference to a chapter 1 goal: \gref{firstsecond}

Reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}

\section{another}

Second reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}

\printindex[goals]
\printindex

\end{document}
```

I've used `refcount` and `\getrefnumber`, otherwise `\index` would produce different entries.

Answer (score 3):

This is so close to a complete solution, built following Holle's index suggestion and using egreg's `imakidx` package, that I decided to post it as an answer rather than as an edit to the question. Still missing:

- the ability to expand the `\BODY` macro from the `environ` package
  inside the call to `\index`,
- guarantee that the expanded `\BODY` always appears first under its goal in the
  Goal References index,  **Edit:** starting the index with a blank space before `\BODY`   fixes this. Incorporate in in egreg's accepted answer.
- single column output for that index. **Edit:** deleting `idxlayout` package fixes this.

Here's the output from the MWE below, which isn't quite "minimal" since I need to make sure that other features still work.

[image: almost right goals index]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[totoc]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

%% columns=1 isn't working
\makeindex[name=goals,title=Goal References,columns=1]

\newcommand{\gref}[1]{%
   [Goal~\ref{goal:#1}]
   \index[goals]{Goal~\ref{goal:#1}!Section \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@goal[1]{%
  \addpenalty{\@highpenalty}%
  \vskip \z@ \@plus \p@ 
  \begingroup
  \parindent\z@
  \rightskip\@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth 
  \leavevmode #1\nobreak\hfil\nobreak\null\par 
  \penalty\@highpenalty
  \endgroup}

\newcommand{\egregaddtocontents}[1]{%   
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\l@goal{#1}}}

% arrange goal numbering by chapter
\newtheorem{Goal}{Goal}[chapter]

\NewEnviron{goal}[1]{%
\begin{Goal}
   \label{goal:#1}
   \index[goals]{Goal~\ref{goal:#1}!BODY here}
   %{\em label:} #1 %comment in/out to restore/suppress printing label
   \normalfont{}\noindent
   \BODY
   \egregaddtocontents{\BODY}
}
[\end{Goal}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{First}

\begin{goal}{firstfirst} 
learn more \LaTeX
\end{goal}

\begin{goal}{firstsecond}
spend time on content, not \LaTeX
\end{goal}

stuff\index{stuff}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{goal}{secondfirst}
have fun in any case\index{fun}
\end{goal}

Chapter contents here, referring to some goals:
\section{whatever}

Reference to a chapter 1 goal: \gref{firstsecond}

Reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}

\section{another}

Second reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}

\printindex[goals]
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg Don't know whether it's appropriate to point particular people at particular questions - but if this isn't easy for you then it's really hard. Feel free to finish my answer and post a new one of your own for me to accept and upvote.

Comment: Do you *really* want to index something in the body of a `goal` environment *and* index the whole contents?

Comment: @egreg Yes. The reader can use the separate index of goal references to see where in the text various goals are addressed. That's easier if the index contains the statement of the goal (the BODY), not just the goal number. The BODY text will always be pretty short. Thanks for the good question and the good answer!

Answer (score 1):

I merged your code with the code of the first given example from the comments. Maybe it's what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% create a new list incl. counter
\newlistof{goalsCounter}{goals}{List of \textbackslash goals}

\AtEndDocument{
\cleardoublepage
\listofgoalsCounter% print the list
}

\newcommand{\gref}[1]{%
   [Goal~\ref{goal:#1}]
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@goal[1]{%
\addpenalty{\@highpenalty}%
\vskip \z@ \@plus \p@
\begingroup
\parindent\z@
\rightskip\@pnumwidth
\parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
\leavevmode #1\nobreak\hfil\nobreak\null\par
\penalty\@highpenalty
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\egregaddtocontents}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\l@goal{#1}}}

% arrange goal numbering by chapter
\newtheorem{Goal}{Goal}[chapter]    
\NewEnviron{goal}[1]{%

%this is new
\refstepcounter{goalsCounter}% step the counter
\addcontentsline{goals}{goalsCounter}{\thegoalsCounter:\quad#1}% add item to list

\begin{Goal}
\label{goal:#1}
%{\em label:} #1 %comment in/out to restore/suppress printing label
\normalfont{}\noindent
\BODY
\egregaddtocontents{\BODY}
}
[\end{Goal}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{First}

\begin{goal}{firstfirst}
learn more \LaTeX
\end{goal}

\begin{goal}{firstsecond}
spend time on content, not \LaTeX
\end{goal}

stuff

\chapter{Second}
\begin{goal}{secondfirst}
have fun in any case
\end{goal}

Chapter contents here, referring to some goals:
\section{whatever}
Reference to a chapter 1 goal: \gref{firstsecond}
Reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}
\section{another}
Second reference to a chapter 2 goal: \gref{secondfirst}    
\end{document}
```

But I don't know why you use the (complicated) `\l@goal`. I think the `tocloft` package do the same job. But maybe you have special reasons for this. In the following example is a solution only with the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% create a new list incl. counter
\newlistof{goalsCounter}{goals}{List of \textbackslash goals}

% a new goal reference command
\newcommand{\goalRef}[1]{ [Goal~\ref{goal:#1}]}

\newenvironment{goal}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{goalsCounter}% step the counter
    \addcontentsline{goals}{goalsCounter}{\thegoalsCounter:\quad#1}% add item to list
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Goal \thegoalsCounter: #1}% add item to the toc
    \label{goal:#1}\textbf{Goal \thegoalsCounter\ #1:}\quad%
}

\AtEndDocument{\listofgoalsCounter}% print the list

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\begin{goal}{FirstFirst}
learn more \LaTeX
\end{goal}
\begin{goal}{FirstSecond}
spend time on content, not \LaTeX
\end{goal}
stuff
\chapter{Second}
\begin{goal}{SecondFirst}
have fun in any case
\end{goal}

Chapter contents here, referring to some goals:
\section{whatever}
Reference to a chapter 1 goal: \goalRef{FirstSecond}\\
Reference to a chapter 2 goal: \goalRef{SecondFirst}
\section{another}
Second reference to a chapter 2 goal:\goalRef{SecondFirst}
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution example with the tocloft package]

Comment: This is a start. But what I need (as in the MWE) is a list of goals _with their text_, each entry followed by a list of _references_ to that goal, with page numbers and links. Your answer also changes the TOC format from my MWE. I think a solution could be built with two indexes, one normal, one for goals - see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-2-or-more-distinct-indexes-in-latex.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Because you wrote: 'I need a list like the list of figures' I provided this example. I think you don't need a 'List of goals' but you need a 'Index of goals'. I'm right? If so you should use the index or the splitindex package. If you are interested in LuaLaTeX this could be an approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55321/10570. Here you can create an 'index' and format the index entries like you want.

Comment: Yes, an index of goals is indeed what I want - as I realized last night and indicated in my previous comment. I will work on that solution when I get a chance. Thanks for your help. I don't use LuaLaTeX and will probably try this without its tools.