# convert outcome of reference to regular number

Tags: cross-referencing, calculations, fp

Is it possible to transform the outcome of a reference (e.g., a line number) to a regular number that I can use in a calculation?
I have this (and works fine):

```
\FPeval{\result}{clip(5+6)} $\result$
```

Now I want to do a calculation involving \lineref{myline}. However,

```
\FPeval{\result}{clip(5+\lineref{myline})} $\result$
```

doesn't work because `\lineref{myline}` is not recognized as a number, I guess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You easiest is to use the [`refcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) which allows for expandable versions of functions to retrieve counter numbers. Here's a small example where line number is extracted from an algorithm:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$\label{myline}% This is line 6 in the algorithm
  \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

Result: \FPeval{\result}{clip(5+\getrefnumber{myline})} $\result$
\end{document}​
```

`\getrefnumber{<label>}` retrieves the counter associated with `<label>`. For calculation of page references, an analogous `\getpagerefnumber` is provided.

Comment: `\getrefnumber` is expandable, therefore it cannot notify LaTeX that the reference
is used &mdash; LaTeX wants to warn because of undefined references. Therefore
package `refcount` provides `\refused` that tells LaTeX about the reference.
`\refused{myline}` is then used outside the expandable context of `\FPeval`.